# googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) won't work on older devices

Tags: android, maps, google-play-services

I've been working with google maps on Android. It shows the map, I can add markers, move the camera.Everything works fine (from Android 2.3 to 4.x) until I put googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true). Then it just work on 4.x, and the app crashes on 2.3. This is what I got on LogCat:

```
  07-23 20:56:25.080: E/dalvikvm(2214): Could not find class 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.plus.provider.PlusProvider.a
    07-23 20:56:25.090: W/dalvikvm(2214): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 406 (Landroid/database/sqlite/SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/plus/provider/PlusProvider;
07-23 20:56:28.906: E/dalvikvm(2214): Could not find class 'android.os.UserManager', referenced from method cbe.c
07-23 20:56:28.906: W/dalvikvm(2214): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 543 (Landroid/os/UserManager;) in Lcbe;

07-23 21:07:53.940: E/CheckinTask(2214): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): java.io.IOException: No Content-Type header
```